# Package Installation Error while trying to start a new web project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I am simply trying to start a new Web API project. I Selected Individual User Account, and pressed Create.

The error message says:

> Package Installation Error
>
> The preinstalled packages have a reference to missing Registry value.  Could not find a Registry key name 'WebFormsVS16' under 'Software\NuGet\Repository

I experimented by creating the missing registry by setting the path by hand. Then gets worse.  I get a slew of error messages

> Package Installation Error
>
> Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from (the path)

The it lists a whole list of messages like

> bootstrap. 3.4.1: Unable to find version 3.4.1 of package bootstrap
>
> Newtonsoft.Jason.12.0.2: Unable to find version 12.0.2

It goes on and one with other "unable to find version.." error messages.

I checked my colleague's registries and he does not even have the Software\NuGet registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be worth trying to repair the Visual Studio install. That is the first thing I try after striking out on google/stack overflow.

Comment: Yep.  That is what did it.